# Does SCSI HBA ata_piix or mptspi correspond to VM's virtual disk in VMware?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, scsi

I have a Debian VM running on VMware where `cat /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/proc_name` returns the following output:

```
ata_piix
ata_piix
mptspi
```

I understand from this that the VM has three (virtual) SCSI HBAs.

How can I find out which of these HBAs (`host0`, `host1`, or `host2`) supports my VM's virtual disk?

vSphere Client shows the VM's `Hard Disk 1` with `Virtual Device Node: SCSI (0:0) Hard Disk 1` and its `SCSI controller 0` as `SCSI Controller Type: LSI Logic Parallel`. The host is apparently running VMware ESXi 6.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this - I've just listed two below.

1. Use `hwinfo` if you have it installed:

   ```
   $ hwinfo --disk
   ...
   28: IDE 06.0: 10600 Disk
   ...
   SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/host0/port-0:6/end_device-0:6/target0:0:6/0:0:6:0
   ...
   Driver: "mpt3sas", "sd"
   Driver Modules: "mpt3sas", "sd_mod"
   Device File: /dev/sdg
   ...
   ```

   The controller is in the SysFS Device Link (PCI ID **01:00.0** identifies it).
2. Find the disks linked to your controllers:

   ```
   $ lspci
   ...
   03:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: VMware PVSCSI SCSI Controller (rev 02)

   $ ls -l /sys/block/sd* |grep 03:00
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 20 10:19 /sys/block/sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 20 10:19 /sys/block/sdb -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sdb
   ```

   In the above, we find the PCI IDs for the disk controller(s) and then find which disks are attached to the controller we're interested in (in this case, **03:00** is the ID of the controller).

*Note:* The above command outputs are from two different machines.

Comment: I went for the 2nd way, it turned out to be `host2`, i.e. `mptspi`. BTW for my VM, `lspci` reports `SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)`. Thx for providing this quick answer.